# Xcode App Submission Error Itms-90096

Tags: xcode, submission, launchimage

I am getting the following error when I archive my app in xcode and try to submit to the app store:

[image]

From what I read on other forums, in order to resolve this issue I need to create a new launch image with the dimension 320x568 and add it to my launch image file.  My question is, how do I create a new placeholder in my launch image file if every placeholder is full?

[image]

As you can see im not sure how to create a new placeholder in my launch image folder to add the new 320x568 image.  Can somebody please advise, thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it worked for me. I created a image (basically, just the app icon) with the 320 (width) x 568 (height) dimensions and saved it to my desktop as a PNG file. I then dragged and dropped it over the 2x placeholder LaunchImage in Xcode (see screenshot). 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyIn5.jpg)
I also created a 640 x 1136 image, saved as PNG and drag-dropped that over the Retina 4 placeholder LaunchImage. That got rid of the error and I was able to then successfully upload the app to the App Store.